# tryCatch in R: how do I capture all warning messages in the function passed to the warning parameter?

Tags: r, try-catch

```
some_f <- function() {
  warning("warning 1")
  warning("warning 2")
}

tryCatch(some_f(),
         warning=function(warn) warn)
```

Output:

```
<simpleWarning in some_f(): warning 1>
```

I need to be able to capture both of the warnings in the function that I pass to the "warning" parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This is a minimal example to catch multiple warnings resulting from your `f()` function:

```
warns <- list()
withCallingHandlers(some_f(), warning = function(warn) {warns <<- append(warns, warn)})
warns

##  $message
##  [1] "warning 1"
##  
##  $call
##  some_f()
##  
##  $message
##  [1] "warning 2"
##  
##  $call
##  some_f()
```

Comment: In contrary to what users expect, this solution won't create a list of the warnings, but this concatenates all elements, as shown in the example. Would be better solved by ```warns <- list()
withCallingHandlers(some_f(), warning = function(warn) {warns <<- c(warns, list(warn))})
warns```. Note that the list append was replaced by creating a list of lists.